# Problems installation Sitecore 9 Commerce XC

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, sitecore-install-framework

I am currently trying to install Sitecore Commerce 9 XC On-Premise locally, and seem to have some problems with the installation script.

I am getting this error message during the installation procedure.

```
[------------------------------------------- InstallModule : InstallModule -------------------------------------------]
I am here?
Installing module:  Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.1.47.zip
http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallModules.aspx?modules=Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.1.47.z
ip
VERBOSE: GET http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallModules.aspx?modules=Sitecore Commerce Experience
Accelerator 1.1.47.zip with 0-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the
subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:




Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step




             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54

            Stack Trace:




[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;
event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) +343
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode,
IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,
IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1381





            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0


At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:255 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:30
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\SXAStorefront.Framework.180501 (4).log
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the
subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:




Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step




             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54

            Stack Trace:




[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;
event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) +343
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode,
IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,
IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1381





            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0


At C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:81 char:2
+     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Verbose
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:03:21
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Master_SingleServer.180501 (19).log
Invoke-RestMethod :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the
subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:




Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step




             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54

            Stack Trace:




[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;
event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) +343
   Sitecore.Install.Items.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode,
IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) +126
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,
IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1381





            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0


At C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Modules\SitecoreUtilityTasks\SitecoreUtilityTasks.psm1:20 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod $urlInstallModules -TimeoutSec 720
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Deploy script:

```
#Requires -Version 3
param(
    [string]$SiteName = "sc90.local",   
    [string]$SiteHostHeaderName = "sxa.storefront.com", 
    [string]$SqlDbPrefix = 'sc90',
    [string]$CommerceSearchProvider = "SOLR"
)

$global:DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$modulesPath=( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "Modules" )
if ($env:PSModulePath -notlike "*$modulesPath*")
{
    $p = $env:PSModulePath + ";" + $modulesPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)
}


$params = @{
        Path = Resolve-Path '.\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json' 
        SiteName = $SiteName
        SiteHostHeaderName = $SiteHostHeaderName 
        InstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$SiteName"
        XConnectInstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$($SiteName)_xconnect"
        CertificateName = $SiteName
        CommerceServicesDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)    #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        CommerceServicesDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments"
        CommerceServicesGlobalDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_Global"       
        SitecoreDbServer = $($Env:COMPUTERNAME)            #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        SitecoreCoreDbName = "$($SqlDbPrefix)_Core"
        SitecoreUsername = "sitecore\admin"
        SitecoreUserPassword = "b"
        CommerceSearchProvider = $CommerceSearchProvider
        SolrUrl = "https://localhost:58/solr"
        #SolrRoot = "c:\\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrRoot =  "C:\Sitecore\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrService = "solr6"
        SolrSchemas = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SolrSchemas" )
        SearchIndexPrefix = ""
        AzureSearchServiceName = ""
        AzureSearchAdminKey = ""
        AzureSearchQueryKey = ""
        CommerceEngineDacPac = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.*\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"       
        CommerceOpsServicesPort = "5015"
        CommerceShopsServicesPort = "5005"
        CommerceAuthoringServicesPort = "5000"
        CommerceMinionsServicesPort = "5010"        
        SitecoreCommerceEngineZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.2.*.zip"        
        SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.*"       
        SitecoreIdentityServerZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.IdentityServer.1.*.zip"
        CommerceEngineCertificatePath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\storefront.engine.cer"       
        SiteUtilitiesSrc = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SiteUtilityPages" )  
        HabitatImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-*.zip"    
        AdvImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Adventure Works Images.zip"    
        CommerceConnectModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Connect*.zip"  
        CEConnectPackageFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect*.update"
        PowerShellExtensionsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-2*.zip"
        #SXAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Experience.Accelerator.*\content\Sitecore Experience Accelerator*.zip"
        SXAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Experience Accelerator*.zip"
        SXACommerceModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontThemeModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Themes*.zip"
        #SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Habitat Catalog*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Habitat Catalog*.zip"

        #MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\assets\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        UserAccount = @{
            Domain = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            UserName = 'CSFndRuntimeUser'
            Password = 'Pu8azaCr'
        }
        BraintreeAccount = @{
            MerchantId = ''
            PublicKey = ''
            PrivateKey = ''
        }
        SitecoreIdentityServerName = "SitecoreIdentityServer"       
    }

if ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "SOLR") {
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Verbose
}
elseif ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "AZURE"){
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip InstallSolrCores
}
```

Files:[image]

Why this error? I am not even sure what it is trying to indicate?

Comment: I think that you are missing some files in your install directory. Please update your question with your powershell install script + screenshot of files that you have in install directory

Comment: Can you also confirm from the sitecore log that xconnect is up an running and XP can access that?